# Side effects of disallowing *.php requests in production environment?

Tags: security

For security in the production environment a company I work with has removed the whole `wp-admin/` directory, and is about to disallow all `*.php` file calls with a `403 Forbidden` HTTP error.

Are there any pitfalls to doing this? (Other than the obvious thing of now allowing administration or other backend functionality).

Are there any subsystems on the backend that I should be concerned with not working right if this is in place?

(Updates to content are done in a secure area, and the process of pushing to production replicates the database and WP files, except `wp-admin/*` files.).

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand how any of that could in any way improve your security. Also how you are supposed to do anything if you don't allow PHP POST, GET and REQUESTS.

Comment: If the site uses jQuery Ajax call, would that break / stop the request?

Comment: Agreed - there are much easier and better ways to improve security.  I'm somewhat curious to see if WordPress would even operate with `*.php` disallowed altogether.

Comment: To address the issue of why you might secure or remove `wp-admin/` see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#Securing_wp-admin

Comment: At that point what don't you just grab the feed, why the replication?

Comment: Let's say plugin "Foo" has a vulnerability -- preventing direct calls to say `wp-content/plugins/foo/Foo.php` would allow the plugin to run only when called from inside other content, but would *disallow* direct calls to the file. The reason I'm asking about `.php` file disallow is because I don't really have a good answer for how or why it works either. But my "Foo" example is the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Grabbing the feed from another WordPress site leaves 2 open and potentially insecure instances of WordPress on the internet. That's not an answer. And no, posting and comments *do not* work on this published WordPress instance. This is a feature not a bug, and questioning this aspect of the question means you are not understanding the basis of my question so can't help me. I appreciate you chiming in, but it's not helpful.

Comment: I understand security, if your company is going to these lengths you should hire someone who knows what they are doing, just disallowing *.php and replicated a site sans wp-admin is odd to say the least and not a real solution.

Comment: @Steven, yes, AJAX calls to `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` would not be possible given this configuration. This ie mentioned at: http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#Securing_wp-admin

Comment: @Wyck, I assure you we have operations people who understand security. They deal with tens of thousands of concurrent connected users and devices continuously in other parts of our business. This is the real deal. What I'm trying to understand it myself, thus the question. :-)

Comment: I think architecturally this is a weird solution to the problem, so I'm not sure how to answer, sorry.

Comment: I have an idea. Why not simply generate HTML pages from one server and just push it out to another server? That way you will only have static HTML pages, never wory about PHP abuse and dont worry about hackers. But to be serious, disallowing *.php would be the same as disallowing *.aspx. It just doesn't make sense. If you code correctly, simply calling a PHP file is not enough to hack your site. If a spacific PHP file reads POS / GET, then you have to quality controll the input. I'm no security expert, but this just sounds wrong in my ears.

Comment: "If you code correctly, simply calling a PHP file is not enough to hack your site" yes, but WordPress and plugins are third party code. Saving to static files is not a bad idea, but for a site with a great deal of content, this has a different downside, that of a much larger file to be replicated. I appreciate the thought though. Ultimately most people are finding the premise of my question bizarre. :-( Hah! So bizarre someone felt the need to downvote. How helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding:
They are going to disallow *.php access from external HTTP requests.

It should not cause a problem.
It's a common security measure to disallow extension access, and if you are using custom permalink structures, you can get around most of the needs to do so.

Since quite a bit of your interactions with WordPress will be in the administration area, you shouldn't run into any problems with core features since you've sandboxed that somewhere else.

BUT, any plugins and themes that have made the assumption that they would be able to call AJAX via a *.php URL, or POST/GET from such a URL, may break. So using extensions may suck.

You may need to take more time in reviewing plugins and themes before saying "this will just work". By doing this, you will create more work for yourself in the long run for the trade of security.

---

Just to be sure, I would setup a default WordPress install, then setup custom permalinks...then leave it up for a bit and watch the access logs.

You can easily see how many hits are going to break because they directly hit *.php extensions.

A smoother way of doing this...might be to simply 301 people to mysite.com/whatevertheyweretryingtogetto.php -> mysite.com/whatevertheyweretryingtogetto

Just chop it off.

Comment: Yes, I've looked at some of the plugins we're using and we appear not to be using anything that has a "public-facing" .php file. I'll have to look at all of them a bit closer. Thanks for the coherent answer!

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, I'm no security expert. But I have worked in big firms that have had good security.

Here are a few things to consider:

- Follow some of the more [standard security measures](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) of WP.
- Rename /wp-admin
- Move database to a server behind a firewall
- Consider using a [PROXY server](http://caleudum.com/wordpress-proxy-setting/)
- And if it is, as Sterling says common security measure, disallow extension access

Comment: wp-admin is indeed removed. database is indeed firewalled. whole site has a load balancing infrastructure in front of it with intrusion detection included.